# PMP documentation without closing date

Tags: time-management

I am a banking professional and would like to have a PMP qualification.

My experience is related to projects, but most of them are continuous projects: each project has a start date but not a closing date. Can I use this kind of project as my experience of project supervision?

Comment: If it doesn't have a close date, it isn't a project.  One of the defining distinctions between "operations" and "project" is that projects have a close date.  That said, (1) Only PMI can answer this question and (2) even operational /continuous efforts tend to include discrete projects.

Comment: Depending on your, experience you could pursue PMP Certification. But it is advisable to get the confirmation on the same from PMI or any affiliated institute that provided a PMP training.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous activities are operations not projects, but even these activities will involve some projects like creating new systems, upgrading, inventing new products or services, changing adminstrative procedures, or a project to get ISO certification for the company.

> > > > Mentioning operations as projects will be a fatal mistake